# Update an podio item field results in empty value

Tags: api, podio

I am using Postman software to test update field of an item in Podio. The field is 'consomme-en-jh'. The value is updated in Podio with an empty value. Do I forget a key value in the body or another thing?[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use this api method: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/update-item-field-values-22367

Please read docs on how to use it and follow cUrl example.
It's hard to tell from your screenshot, but verify:

1. Url should be like:
   `https://api.podio.com/item/<item-id>/value/<field-id>`
2. Method is
   `PUT`
3. Body is new value (and it depends on your field type, value
   might be very different)

Comment: Thank you Pavlo - I worked on it yesterday and I see that there is a 'code' button in postman where I can convert my request in cUrl. I can now compare easily my request with the example you mentioned. I hope I will succeed ;-)